# D Programming Language Tutorial - Area of a Circle - Error: Undefined identifier toFloat

Tags: d

I just started learning D. When I build this tutorial file: http://www.dprogramming.com/CA_prompt.html

(directly from the D site), I get these errors:

```
circle.d|24|Error: template std.stdio.readln cannot deduce function from argument types !()(File), candidates are:|
/usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/stdio.d|2818|       std.stdio.readln(S = string)(dchar terminator = '\x0a') if (isSomeString!S)|
/usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/stdio.d|2851|       std.stdio.readln(C)(ref C[] buf, dchar terminator = '\x0a') if (isSomeChar!C && is(Unqual!C == C) && !is(C == enum))|
/usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/stdio.d|2858|       std.stdio.readln(C, R)(ref C[] buf, R terminator) if (isSomeChar!C && is(Unqual!C == C) && !is(C == enum) && isBidirectionalRange!R && is(typeof(terminator.front == (dchar).init)))|
circle.d|25|Error: undefined identifier toFloat|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Any ideas as to why?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

So I end up with this:

```
import std.conv;
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import std.math;

const real pi = std.math.PI;

void main()
{
   try
   {
     const char [] chRadius;
      float r;
      writef("Enter the radius: ");
      chRadius = chomp(readln());
      r = to!float(chRadius);
      writefln("Circle area = %f", pi*r*r);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      writefln("catch %s", e.toString());
   }
}
```

The build message is this:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Area of a Circle (compiler: Digital Mars D Compiler) ===|
circle.d|24|Error: cannot modify const expression chRadius|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

EDIT 2: Changed `const char[]` to `string`, and everything works! Thanks!

Comment: I've never looked at d before, but it looks to me like your problem is that readln isn't getting any arguments it can figure out. Perhaps the libraries have been updated since the tutorial was written 6 years ago? Just my 2 cents worth.

Comment: Check the following line: `// Written T. McKeaveney, April 2008. `. D has changed a lot since 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @miken32 mentioned, that tutorial is pretty out of date -- the source given will need to be modified for a modern d compiler:

1. Call `readln` without arguments to read from stdin. You can use `File.readln` to read from a file handle, but in this case just use `chRadius = chomp(readln())`
2. use `string` instead of `char[]` (though you could also use `const(char)[]`)
3. use `to!float` instead of `toFloat`. The `!float` indicates that the type `float` is a compile time argument to the generic function `to`

Comment: Thanks much! I changed `char[]` to `const char[]` at first, and the compiler still didn't like it. Everything worked with `string`, though!

Comment: sorry, that should have been `const(char) []`. I've fixed it above, but you're typically still better off using string (which is equivalent to `immutable(char) []`. See [Arrays](http://dlang.org/arrays.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some compilation errors because this tuto. is based on **D1** (old, unmaintained, obsolete version of the lang.) and not **D2** (actively developed and widely used version of the lang.)

If you want to compile this then setup [**D1 v 1.076** (*bottom of the page*)](http://dlang.org/download.html).